# Filter OSM with osmosis for specific amenity

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, bin, cloudmade, osmosis

I have downloaded the Ireland file from cloudmade for osmosis (500 MB) and placed it in the osmosis bin folder, which osmosis reads fine. I would now like to create a new file with just those places tagged with `Tag:amenity=fast food`. My directory is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\osmosis-0.41\bin>
```

I'm currently following the [tag-filter guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage#--tag-filter_.28--tf.29) on the OSM wiki but can't get it to work. Here's what I'm trying:

```
     C:\Program Files (x86)\osmosis-0.41\bin>osmosis --read-xml ireland.osm 
--tf accept-nodes amenity=fast food --write-xml output.osm
```

And here's the error I get:

org.openstreetmap.osmosois.core.Osmosis main 
SEVERE:  Execution aborted. 
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: 
Only one default (un-named) argument can exist per task. 
Arguments 6 and 4 have no name.....

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put your filter value among "-s, like this: amenity="fast food"

Comment: Thanks Plutoz. I got the error "Thread for task 1-read-xml failed... Unable to open file for writing". This was due to administrator privileges, but when I copied it to the desktop and included "fast_food" I got the output file in a couple of seconds.

Comment: Hmm, should I be able to open the output file directly in JOSM? JOSM doesn't load from it (file size is 127 MB)

Comment: hmm. 127 MB looks too much. I will check the correct sintax when I access to a pc not just a phone.
If it will okay, you will be able to open the output with JOSM

Comment: Ok, solution is quite simple: you have to use --tf reject-ways and --tf reject-relations already.
So, the full command looks like similar this: osmosis --read-xml file="ireland.osm" --tf accept-nodes amenity="fast_food"
 --tf reject-ways --tf reject-relations  --write-xml file="out.osm"
I notice you should use fast_food (with underline).

Comment: Ah yes, that works! 197 kB is a lot more reasonable. Is there a way I can overlay this on just the basic map with the roads? Or is my best bet to mine this xml for the data and then paste it into something like batchgeo?

Comment: You can do the same with the ways, too (--tg accept ways highway=* --used-nodes), then open both files with JOSM as a seperated layers. There you could merge them to one file, if you wish. There is a method to do the same with osmosis, too, but I think, this solution is at least simple.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put "" and ',' on amenity=fast food.

it should be amenity="fast,food"

Comment: Actually I think amenity=fast_food should be done, as that matches the OSM data model.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. In my case, the command was split over several lines using `\`:

```
osmosis \
  --read-xml ireland.osm \
  --tf accept-nodes amenity="fast food" \
  --write-xml output.osm
```

The reason of the error was that **there was a space after one of the backslashes**.